# CSS checkbox styling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have my checkboxes and I am trying to style it with the following CSS.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(/static/app/images/check_no.svg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background: url(/static/app/images/check_yes.svg);
    content: '';
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="check1">
  <input id="id_contract_name" name="contract_name" type="checkbox"> 
    <label for=" id_contract_name "> 
      <span class="chk_contract"></span>   Name on Contract
    </label>
</div>


<div class="check2">
  <input id="id_is_ceo" name="is_ceo" type="checkbox"> 
  <label for=" id_is_ceo "> 
    <span></span>  CEO?
  </label>
</div>
```

The checkboxes are inside my form.

This does not work when I click my checkbox. I am new to styling and let me know where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces around the name in the `for` attribute, remove them.

**Working demo:**

```css
 input[type="checkbox"]{
display: none;
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
   }

      input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(/static/app/images/check_no.svg);

      }

     input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
background: url(/static/app/images/check_yes.svg);
content: '';
color: #fff;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
       /*added this to show the behavior here on SO*/
       background-color: #000
 }
```

```html
     <div class="check1">
          <input id="id_contract_name" name="contract_name" type="checkbox"> 
          <label for="id_contract_name"> 
              <span class="chk_contract"></span>   Name on Contract
          </label>
      </div>


     <div class="check2">
          <input id="id_is_ceo" name="is_ceo" type="checkbox"> 
          <label for="id_is_ceo"> 
              <span></span>  CEO?
          </label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention id or class in CSS.
And if you want to add css dynamically then you have to use javascript or jquery.

```css
 #id_contract_name{
display: none;
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
   }

      #id_is_ceo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(/static/app/images/check_no.svg);

      }

     input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
background: url(/static/app/images/check_yes.svg);
content: '';
color: #fff;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
     <div class="check1">
          <input id="id_contract_name" name="contract_name" type="checkbox"> 
          <label for=" id_contract_name "> 
              <span class="chk_contract"></span>   Name on Contract
          </label>
      </div>


     <div class="check2">
          <input id="id_is_ceo" name="is_ceo" type="checkbox"> 
          <label for=" id_is_ceo "> 
              <span></span>  CEO?
          </label>
      </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. The OP wants to hide the checkbox and display custom graphics instead of it, based on checked property.